# How to pass two parameters to a select to a SELECT query in vtiger?

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm, dynamic-picklist-vtiger

I would like to pass two parameters to a SELECT query for one scenario in a vtiger custom function. Like below ..

```
function start_date($projectid, $stage){

$adb = PearDatabase::getInstance();

        $stage = "Stage-0";

        $data = $adb->pquery("SELECT startdate FROM vtiger_projecttask WHERE projectid = ?", array($projectid), array($stage);

        $num_rows = $adb->num_rows($data);

        for($i=0; $i<$num_rows; $i++) {
            $col3[$i] = $adb->query_result($data, $i,'startdate');      
        }
}
```

But it is not allowing me to execute this type of query. How can i form a query with two parameters in vtiger?

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: Answer which i have given is the perfect as per your question. Can you please tell what you exactly required if you doesn't get your solution so i can update my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this code as below. This will work.

```
function start_date($projectid, $stage){

$adb = PearDatabase::getInstance();

    $stage = "Stage-0";

    $data = $adb->pquery("SELECT startdate FROM vtiger_projecttask WHERE projectid = ? and stage = ?", array($projectid,$stage));

    $num_rows = $adb->num_rows($data);

    for($i=0; $i<$num_rows; $i++) {
        $col3[$i] = $adb->query_result($data, $i,'startdate');      
    }
}
```

Comment: Great to hear that